# PrimeNG data tables - export selected rows

Tags: angular, mean-stack, primeng

I have the following PrimeNG data table below and I'm trying to export to csv only the rows that I've selected where a selection column is defined here:

```
<p-column field="marked" header="Marked" [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
```

Here is the entire data table defined:

```
<p-column field="marked" header="Selected Column" [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
    <p-header>
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
            <button type="button" pButton icon="fa-file-o" iconPos="left" label="Export To CSV" (click)="dt.exportCSV()" style="float:right"></button>
        </div>
    </p-header>
    <p-column field="marked" header="Selected Column" [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
    <p-column field="id" header="count7" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="name" header="count6" [sortable]="false"></p-column>
    <p-column field="field1" header="count5" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="field2" header="count4" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="field3" header="count3" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="field4" header="count2" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
    <p-column field="field5" header="Count1" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

When I export this table now using the dt.exportCSV() command, the column "Selected Column" in the csv contains only the value 'undefined'.

So, I'd like to be able to only return either the selected rows, or have the rows in the csv be marked "true" or some other value.  Thoughts?

Thanks for all the help!

EDIT:  Adding my defined dt function:

```
   <p-dataTable #dt [value]="records" 
 [(selection)]="selectedRecords" exportFilename="discover" dataKey="id"
                [paginator]="true" [rows]="20" [headerCheckboxToggleAllPages]="true">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that question is old, but just in case someone is looking for an answer. Here is how we do it.

```
dt.exportCSV({ selectionOnly: true });
```

We are using `PrimeNG version: 4.3.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined dt in your template.  in primeNG samples, dt is defined as a template variable:

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="cars">
  <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
  <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
  <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
  <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable> 

<button type="button" pButton icon="fa-file-o" iconPos="left" label="CSV" (click)="dt.exportCSV()"></button>
```

You need to define it as well like they do with the #dt syntax on your p-dataTable.  Looks like it is intended to export the entire data table and not on individual columns though if that is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks bryan for the reply!  So I added my defined dt function in the original post.  What I'm looking for is a way to export just the rows that I select from the datatable.  The selector column is defined:

<p-column field="marked" header="Selected Column" [style]="{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>

Yeah so I want to export just the rows which I've clicked the checkbox that's provided by the defined above column.    Thanks for the help!

Comment: Like I said, I don't believe the primeNG API provides for such a function, the exportCSV() function is on the data table and doesn't take parameters... You would need to write your own, the data table api exposes selection events you could use to capture the selected data, and then run a function on click that takes the selected data and turns it into a csv.  Creating a CSV is just creating a comma delimited string and there are a few SO answers about how to export a CSV for download.  Or maybe you can find a plugin for it somewhere, but it's pretty straight forward stuff.

Comment: However, I think you're seeing the odd behavior you're seeing because the exportCSV function is probably meant for simple tables, and you're trying to use it with a table that has grouped columns, so it probably doesn't know how to csv export that data, since there could be a few different valid interpretations of how to do that.